# Чи однакова семантика слів: біли́зна чи білизна́?

Tags: значення-слів, наголос

Чи однакова семантика слів: біли́зна чи білизна́?

Comment: Це запитання? Якщо запитання — то в чому саме воно полягає? (Ви ж начебто самі все розказали.) Якщо це спроба надати інформацію (а не спитати), то перенесіть, будь ласка, відповідь у поле «Your Answer».

Comment: Вибачте, ще вивчаю, як перенести. Обов’язково врахую Ваше зауваження!

Comment: Технічно перенести дуже просто: натискаєте «edit» («редагувати») під запитанням, виділяєте фрагмент тексту, що має стати відповіддю, вирізаєте його в буфер обміну (Ctrl+X), натискаєте «Save Edits» («Зберегти зміни»), натискаєте «Answer Your Question» («відповісти на власне запитання»), натискаєте «Yes…», вставляєте вирізаний фрагмент з буферу обміну (Ctrl+V) і натискаєте «Post Your Answer» («Надіслати Вашу відповідь»). Але організаційно — Вам ще треба буде розширити якось Ваше запитання, щоб після перенесення відповіді в належне їй місце воно не стало закоротким, бо тут не люблять закороткі.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/bilyzna) подає, що це лексеми із диференційованим наголосом, тобто залежно від наголосу значення слова змінюється. Отож:

**Біли́зна**

**1.** Вироби з тканин (переважно білі) для одягання на тіло або для побутових потреб (на постіль і т. ін.). *Прийшов він до річки, поскидав з себе білизну* (Павло Чубинський, II, 1878, 401);

**2.**  Хижа прісноводна промислова риба.

**Білизна́** *іменник* до **бі́лий**; білість. *Весело сміялася [школа] білизною своїх стін* (Юрій Збанацький, Малин. Дзвін, 1958).

Подібно написано і в [Тлумачному словнику української мови](http://eslovnyk.com/%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0):

Білизна

I -и, ж., збірн.
Спідній одяг, який одягають безпосередньо на тіло (труси, кальсони, ліфчики, комбінації тощо) або тканинні вироби для побутових потреб (простирадла, наволочки, скатертини і т. ін.). Раніше виготовлявся з бавовняної, льняної або шовкової тканини, переважно білого кольору.

••
Чолові́ча біли́зна — труси, кальсони, майки, футболки, натільна сорочка та ін.

••
Жіно́ча біли́зна — жіночі трусики, ліфчики, комбінації та ін.

••
Пості́льна біли́зна — простирадла, наволочки, підодіяльники та ін.

••
Столо́ва біли́зна — скатертини, серветки, рушники та ін.

II -и, ж.
Хижа прісноводна промислова риба.

Проте тут наголос подано лише один: біли́зна. Отже, в останньому словнику лише враховано лише один із омонімів.

Також згадку про омографи можна знайти і в [Новому довіднику: Українська мова. Українська література](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=12632), де вказано, що:
"Другу групу омонімів становлять слова, що збігаються тільки в частині граматичних форм. Це морфологічні неповні омоніми. Вони поділяються
на кілька підгруп, зокрема на омографи:

орган — орган,

замок — замок,

сім’я — сім’я, [...]

*білизна — білизна,*

насип — насип,

радій — радій"

Отже, лексеми "біли́зна" та "білизна́" є семантично різними і це показує саме диференційований наголос.

Comment: Порада: якщо слово починається на літери А–М, використовуйте не [старий академічний «Словник української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х років](http://sum.in.ua/), а [новий академічний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/) (зокрема: [біли́зна¹](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4355&page=162), [біли́зна²](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4356&page=162), [білизна́](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4357&page=162)). (Але це, звісно, суто на Ваш розсуд, це жодним чином не вимога і навіть не прохання.)

Comment: Дякую! Врахую Вашу пораду!